# Are there plans to develop a golang version of Android?

Tags: android, go

I've looked around a bit but I can't find a discussion about a version of Android built directly from `golang` source code and little or no Java.

I see there's an Android 9 (Go edition) version. But it looks like it's just more Java with Golang bindings: https://www.android.com/versions/go-edition. Or is this a native `Go` Android?

Comment: Go edition is just a naming, it has nothing to do with Golang.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because entirely 100% off topic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I see there's an Android 9 (Go edition) version. But it looks like it's just more Java with Golang bindings

No. Android Go is a line of Android apps designed for use on low-end Android devices. Android Go has nothing to do with:

- the Go programming language
- the Go strategy board game
- the Go square on a traditional Monopoly board
- etc.

> I've looked around a bit but I can't find a discussion about a version of Android built directly from golang source code and little or no Java.

That is because it does not exist.

Comment: [Fuchsia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Fuchsia) may (or may not) eventually displace Android, and parts of it are wtitten in Go; but only parts, and the other parts are written in C, C++, Dart, and may be something else. And since Android is the kernel plus some amount of Java API and userspace, I doubt it would even be a good idea to (re-)write _all_ of this in Go, especially the kernel.

Comment: What a mess. Doesn't look like Fushia is going to save us. But a complete rewrite of kernel, APIs and user space in golang might not? How can C be better in any way than Go?

Comment: I guess the Linux stack will need to all be rewritten as well.

Comment: The only choice could be a WebAssembly API accessible for userspace. That way any language compiled go wasm could use it. This is where the web goes so I see no reason why native OSes  wouldn't follow.  So it's not all lost but today looks like you need to use Java to write Android apps and Swift/Objective-C to write iOS apps...I already regret using Go in my latest mobile app.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a wiki with clear steps to achieve compiling a golang app and installing onto android

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile

The toy android app shows an animated triangle which follows your touch as it moves about ... this actually worked when I discovered above wiki I believe from https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9875886   To quote their wiki

---

> The Go mobile subrepository adds support for mobile platforms (Android and iOS) and provides tools to build mobile applications.
>
> There are two strategies you can follow to include Go into your mobile stack:

- Writing all-Go native mobile applications.
- Writing SDK applications by generating bindings from a Go package and invoke them from Java (on Android) and Objective-C (on iOS).

Writing golang for mobile can be like writing c++ for mobile - great for writing firmware level servers say for HLS (http-live-streaming) which live below any app to which apps make calls to

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the effort though it didn't really address my question.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it is possible to compile Go to both JavaScript and WASM. I've use the WASM support to build an application that work across all modern browsers. (incl. modern mobile browsers)

The way I do it is that I load the Go program in a background worker, I then use a channel to talk to the Go program as it was an API running locally. My primary reason for doing so was to leverage some of the functionality in the standard library, specifically, the cryptographic APIs.

Comment: I suppose using WASM on mobile would result in performant apps that aren't native.